# Spark on Yarn Resource Management on Amazon EMR: How to utilize all available cores for spark job execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have a spark job running on a EMR cluster with following cluster configuration:

**Master** : 1 : m4.2xlarge: 32 GiB of memory, 8 vCPUs. 
**Core** : 2 :
   m4.2xlarge: 32 GiB of memory, 8 vCPUs. 
 **Task Nodes** : Upto 52 :
   r4.2xlarge: 61 GiB of memory, 8 vCPUs.

---

Here is my spark submit configuration based on this blog:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2mxg.png): https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ .

spark.yarn.executor.memory=19g 
spark.executor.cores=3 
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2g 
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g 
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=7 
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=7 
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1000 
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
spark.yarn.maxAttempts=1

I am running a cross join of 2 datasets for an use case. And I am trying to utilize every bit of memory and CPU available on cluster that I can using above settings. I am able to successfully utilize all memory available in the cluster but not **CPU**. I see that even though **432 cores are available**, but spark job is able to utilize **only 103 cores are being used** as shown in screenshot. I see same behaviour when job is run in yarn-client mode (zeppelin) or yarn-cluster mode.

I am not sure what setting is missing or is incorrect. Any suggestions to resolve this is appreciated.   [image]

Comment: I think the correct memory setting for the executors is `spark.executor.memory` not `spark.yarn.executor.memory`. Can you try changing it?

Comment: Sure. Let me try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing this in YARN ui probably you have to add this in `yarn-site.xml`

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator`

I had the same confusion. Actually while using `DefaultResourceCalculator` in Yarn UI its only calculates memory usage, behind the scene it may have been using more than 1 core but you will see only 1 core used. On the other hand `DominantResourceCalculator` calculates both core and memory for resource allocation and shows actual number of core and memory.

You can also enable ganglia or see EMR metrics for more details.